# Is there any particular study on the following group

Tags: ideals

The set of all principal fractional ideals of $Q(i)$ of the form $(\frac{a+bi}{c})$ where $a^2+b^2=c^2$ with multiplication of ideals form a group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the norm $1$ elements in $\Bbb Q(i)^*$. Call this group $G$.
By Hilbert 90, each element of $G$ is $z/\overline z$ for some $z\in \Bbb Q(i)^*$. Thus there is a surjective homomorphism $\pi:\Bbb Q(i)^*\to G$
with $\pi(z)=z/\overline z$. Its kernel is $\Bbb Q^*$ and so $G
\cong \Bbb Q(i)^*/\Bbb Q^*$.